# How to migrate a folder encrypted with eCryptfs to EncFS

Tags: encryption

I have a large folder encrypted with eCryptfs and synced with Dropbox. 
Is somehow possibile to migrate it to EncFS without re-encrypting it and thus without re-upload it to Dropbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Encfs and Ecryptfs use different format. The only way to convert between them is to decrypt one and encrypt for the other.

Comment: +1. If keeping the data encrypted is important, I wouldn't actually "decrypt" anything to disk, just mount & copy into the new format